# Чем отличаются типы процессоров? Почему в ARM такой хаос?

Tags: arm, процессор

Вопросы теоретические и взаимосвязанные. А чем меж собой различаются стандартные ПК-процессоры `i386-i686, amd64`, PowerPC (вроде бы из той же оперы, да и в QEMU заводятся точно так же), MIPS (насколько мне известно, используется в некоторых роутерах), ARM `(armv4l-armv8l, или же armeabi/armhf/aarch64)`, SPARC, не говоря о куче крайне малоизвестных архитектур, которые ты в жизни только в QEMU и встретишь, если не будешь проявлять реального интереса к ним. Для тех, кто не понял:

```
 ~ $ qemu-system-[Tab]
qemu-system-alpha
qemu-system-arm
qemu-system-aarch64
qemu-system-aarch64-be
qemu-system-x86
qemu-system-x86-64
qemu-system-ppc
qemu-system-ppc64
qemu-system-ppc64el
qemu-system-mips
qemu-system-xtensa
qemu-system-xtensaeb
qemu-system-m68k
...
```

В чем особенность каждой из этих архитектур, чем они различаются?

И почему в ARM-подобных архитектурах творится полный хаос? Условно говоря, я на Intel и AMD одной битности могу установить ровно одну и ту же ОС, одно и то же ядро Linux/Unix, одни и те же драйвера под одну и ту же периферию, использовать одни и те же [относительно] низкоуровневые программы (загрузчик, ядро, драйвера) и не мучиться с не слишком низкоуровневой разработкой под i[3-6]86/amd64. А вот в ARM нужно морочить голову с конкретным процессором. Скажем так, на двух Intel-ах одной битности, или даже Intel и AMD одной битности одни и те же загрузчик и ядро заведутся без проблем. А в ARM даже наипохожих моделей такого не будет! И все хуже тем, что есть не просто процессоры, а SoC (System on a Crystal), и их составляющей является не только процессор (причём не один: например, в Qualcomm Snapdragon 660 используется 4 ядра Cortex-A53 и 4 ядра Cortex-A73), но и видеочип, камера, WiFi адаптер и много чего ещё. Ещё тяжелее, если нужно виртуализировать ARM, мой прошлый вопрос был как раз про это. Даже в QEMU есть поддержка не всех процессоров, а уж SoC там не эмулируешь, по крайней мере, без танцев с бубном.

Конечно, есть попытки устранить этот хаос. Да, я сейчас говорю про UEFI - своего рода прослойку между процессором, его базовыми микропрограммами, BIOS, aboot и собственно ОС, её загрузчиком и ядром. Ведь UEFI уже сам предоставляет операционной системе часть драйверов и относительно унифицированную систему загрузки, а порой и возможность "залезть" в систему как бы до загрузки самого ядра или даже загрузчика. Иногда дело вообще доходит до лёгкого доступа к файловой системе, EFI Shell и хоть какого-то доступа в сеть!! По сути, UEFI - это уже сама по себе микро-ОС.

Не менее интересен, правда, и сам UEFI, и, преимущественно мобильные, ARM-ы. Дело в том, что есть такая вещь, как TPM (на ПК) и TEE (ARM). По сути, TEE - это отдельная ОС, работающая с ключами к основной ОС. Но, она даже не прекращает работу при запуске Android! Более того, к ней ОС даже обращается когда-то (вспоминаю Linux драйвер qseecomd). Вот как работает параллельная, одновременная загрузка двух ОС сразу - непонятно, у меня это не укладывается в голове. Именно одновременная загрузка, а не возможность загрузить одну из множества установленных систем.

Я прекрасно понимаю, почему создан ARM и его аналоги RISC-V и MIPS, в чем преимущества и недостатки стандартных процессоров x86 и ARM друг перед другом. Но мне все равно до конца не понятно, почему так различны (и почему вообще существует столько архитектур) все эти архитектуры, в чем их особенности, преимущества и недостатки. И чем объясняется ТАКОЙ хаос в ARM с ядрами, драйверами, загрузчиками.

Comment: Я думаю, афтар сам ответит на свой вопрос (подозреваю, для этого и спросил:)

Comment: В архитектуре ARM нет никакого хаоса. Программы, скомпилированные под aarch64, будут работать на любом устройстве aarch64 (вы ж не думаете, что Google Play хранит десятки тысяч версий одного и того же Android-приложения под разные модели телефонов?). Проблема ARM в том, что у него нет общего стандарта для загрузки и определения оборудования, аналогичному BIOS/UEFI и Plug-and-Play из мира x86, поэтому приходится готовить индивидуальные загрузчики и device tree для ОС под каждое устройство отдельно. Но это касается только ОС; с программами, как я уже отметил ранее, никакого хаоса нет

Comment: andreymal, вы не о том говорите. Приложения Android вообще работают на Java, а она переводится даже не в обычный код, как на C++, а в байт-код, интерпретируемый Java машиной. Коли уж вы пытаетесь поднять такую тему - ну хоть бы драйвера или программы на C в пример привели

Comment: @RandomDice779 я о том говорю. Очень многие приложения Android написаны на C++, работают через Android NDK и компилируются под конкретную архитектуру почти без участия Java.

Comment: эм, перечитайте ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО вопрос. Во1, откуда вообще столько архитектур и в чем их особенности. Во2, делается акцент именно на крайне низкоуровневых вещах - ядрах, загрузчиках, драйверах. При чем здесь приложения Android, мне не ясно

Comment: да и разрабатывай ты хоть на Python (киви), Kotlin, Java, даже Dart - все упирается в крайне высокоуровневую машину, zygote, Java Dalvik. А я говорю про совсем другое.

Comment: Вообще UEFI для ARM [очень даже существует](https://developer.arm.com/Architectures/Unified%20Extensible%20Firmware%20Interface), но производители устройств почему-то не спешат его использовать (возможно, им выгоден вендорлок?). Но если для устройства придумать загрузчик, который будет эмулировать UEFI, то становится возможно запустить на устройстве какую угодно UEFI-совместимую операционную систему — [можно даже запустить Windows 11 на обычном телефоне](https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?showtopic=884586) (правда, нужно будет ещё драйвера откуда-то достать)

Comment: Хм, и вопрос-то как раз и в том: а почему под ARM нету общего стандарта загрузки? Вспомнил, есть u-boot, но он используется мало и редко где. В основном - подсобранный под конкретный SoC aboot, xbl/sbl, а отсюда и ядро Linux. Или вообще какой-то свой суп прямо в процессоре...

Comment: Да, я знаю (и даже говорил), что есть UEFI на ARM. Про запуск Windows 11 на телефоне - я тоже в курсе, я сейчас как раз коплю на такой телефон - OnePlus 6, там как раз Qualcomm SDM845, да ещё реальный DualBoot (потому что A/B девайс, можно менять метки загрузки прямиком с Recovery): поставлю себе туда Kali (не Nethunter, а полноценный Linux), либо LFS/Gentoo. С EDK там проблем вроде бы нет, а в xbl там как раз настоящий UEFI сидит.

Comment: На моём устройстве legacy (впрочем, так на всех Qualcomm-ах аж до SDM820 включительно) - т е, хотя есть и xbl, и реверс-инжиниринг говорит, что там есть что-то из мира UEFI, но по большей части там "в лоб" грузится aboot. Видел упоминание(!) про edk на китайском форуме, видел, как запускали GRUB (могу дать ссылку).

Comment: Касательно драйверов — в x86 так-то тот же самый хаос. Вероятно, вы его не заметили просто потому, что в ОС уже встроены тысячи драйверов для основных устройств. Однако часто бывает, что после установки Windows на x86-компьютер не работает графика в родном разрешении, нет звука, нет интернета, иногда могут не работать даже клавиатура и мышь (если USB-контроллер слишком «экзотический») — потому что в Windows не оказалось нужных драйверов. При подключении к интернету Windows автоматически качает недостающие драйвера (а во времена XP их приходилось искать вручную — я много намучался тогда)